# If statement in powershell with -lt value for date does not calculate properly for years?

Tags: powershell, date, if-statement

I've been using this script for about a year now and it seems any values with the year as 22 are not getting treated as greater than the current year of 21... am I not formatting properly?  The csv file is just a username,MM/DD/YY format.  The specific part of the script that is not working due to dates being next year is: if($today -lt $EndDate)...  seems to work for months and days comparatively, but not for years?

In my test file I have one user who has a date of 01/03/22 and the script says the date has ended (meaning $today is not less than the $enddate value, when it is actually next year)

Any pointers?

```
$Import_csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\namesanddates.csv"

# Get today's date
$today = Get-Date -format MM/dd/yy

# Begin import csv process

$Import_csv | ForEach-Object {

    # Retrieve DN of User
    $UserDN = (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Name).distinguishedName
    
    # Error check missing date - set to tomorrow
    $EndDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(1).ToString("MM/dd/yy")
    # Try to use date entered from file
    $EndDate   = (Get-Date $_.date).toString("MM/dd/yy")

    Write-Host "Current User:" $UserDN
    Write-Host "End Date in file:" $EndDate

if($today -lt $EndDate){
    Write-Host "User affected:" $UserDN
    Write-Host "Moving Accounts....." $UserDN

}else{
    Write-Output "User account date ended for:" $UserDN
    }
} 
Write-Host "Script Complete"
```

UPDATE:  Thanks everyone for their feedback - by taking out the .toString conversion and excluding any formatting - Powershell seems to import the dates properly without intervention and then the comparison works.  HOWEVER - If I leave the "-format MM/dd/yy" in the code, the less than comparison fails still.  Both variables are shown as datetime with | % gettype - but it still says that 01/03/22 is less than today's date.

I changed my code to the following and it appears to work properly now - it seems the "format" option is what is borking the -lt comparison.

```
$Import_csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\namesanddates.csv"

# Get today's date
$today = Get-Date 

# Begin import csv process

$Import_csv | ForEach-Object {

    # Retrieve DN of User
    $UserDN = (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Name).distinguishedName
    
    # Error check missing date - set to today
    $EndDate = $today
    # Try to use date entered from file
    $EndDate = Get-Date $_.date

    Write-Host "Current User:" $UserDN
    Write-Host "End Date in file:" $EndDate

if($today -lt $EndDate){
    Write-Host "User affected:" $UserDN
    Write-Host "Moving Accounts....." $UserDN

}else{
    Write-Output "User account date ended for:" $UserDN
    }
} 
Write-Host "Script Complete"
```

Comment: When you do ToString, you convert it to a string, the comparison will then be a string comparison, not a date comparison. For example, the string 2/1/21 will be greater than the string 1/1/22.

Comment: _Always use [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-6.0) to compare Dates and Times_

Comment: as others have pointed out ... **_unless it is absolutely required, DO NOT compare date strings ... instead, compare datetime objects._**

Comment: Get all date into a [datetime] type. Do not use strings unless you have ISO-8601, `yyyy-MM-dd` formatted strings.

Answer (score 0):

As Others Mentioned, the problem here is that you compare date object ($today) with string ($EndDate )

you need to modify it as follow

```
Import_csv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\namesanddates.csv"

# Get today's date
$today = Get-Date -format MM/dd/yy

# Begin import csv process
$Import_csv | ForEach-Object {

# Retrieve DN of User
$UserDN = (Get-ADUser -Identity $_.Name).distinguishedName

# use date entered from file
EndDate   = Get-Date $_.date

Write-Host "Current User:" $UserDN
Write-Host "End Date in file: $($EndDate.toString("MM/dd/yy"))"

if($today -lt $EndDate){
    Write-Host "User affected:" $UserDN
    Write-Host "Moving Accounts....." $UserDN
}
else{
    Write-Output "User account date ended for:" $UserDN
    }
} 
Write-Host "Script Complete"
```

Comment: Having "-format MM/dd/yy" on the variable $today is what is apparently making it fail - I don't quite understand why - but even with both of my variables $today and $enddate being datetime, the less than comparison is not accurate when I include the -format MM/dd/yy.  Letting powershell import the format on it's own allows the less than comparison to execute correctly.  I updated my post - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Taken as strings, it makes sense.  One thing to do is have the left side be a datetime type in the comparison, and the right side will get converted automatically.

```
$today = Get-Date  # 12/24/21
$today | % gettype

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     DateTime                                 System.ValueType


$today -lt '01/03/22'

True
```

Usually people use date strings like this, which can be sorted:

```
Get-Date -format yyyy/MM/dd

2021/12/24
```

Comment: Thank you for the troubleshooting information - with your input I was able to determine that even when not using strings, but using the value types of DateTime, comparisons were still not working when the format was set to MM/dd/yy.

Thankfully PS is smart enough to import a format MM/dd/yy and autoconvert it correctly to it's own format without any input.   I am unable to change the format as the export is coded that way by another system.  

By taking out the -format MM/dd/yy and .toString options - it seems to work properly on its own.